# fb.ui send method not working for test users in facebook

Tags: facebook, sdk, send

I'm using the javascript SDK to fire the send method of fb.ui. It works if I'm logged in as myself and send the messages to other developers on my team. When I log on as a test user and send to another test user, there is no error but the receiver never gets the message.

Code below shows click event from my button:

```
$(".invite_fb_friends").click(function() {
    <?php 
        $subject = __("Please check out Volved", "volved", "volved");
        if (isset($current_user->volved_cause)) {
            $p = get_post($current_user->volved_cause);
            $invite_id = get_user_personal_invite();

            $description = sprintf(__("Follow this link and join me in supporting %s, or a cause of your choice!"), 
                $p->post_title);
            $link = site_url("/cause/". $p->post_name . "/?invite_id=" . $invite_id);
            $picture = get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/images/cause_images/' . $p->post_name . '/logo.jpg';
        } else {
            //No cause chosen
            $description = __("If you follow this link, you'll learn about Volved. If you like, sign up and start making a difference."); 
            $link = site_url("/");
            $picture = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/logo64.png'; 
        }
        //call below documented at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/
    ?>

    res = FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: '<?php echo $subject; ?>',
        link: '<?php echo $link; ?>',
        //picture: '<?php echo $picture; ?>', //Does not seem to work with valid URL. HTML shows URL but no pic displayed. Leaving blank shows picture of sender
        //redirect_uri:  filling this in creates an error on facebook
        description: '<?php echo $description; ?>'
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you duplicate the issue in the Graph API Exporer?  If so, then it's a bug.  If you cannot, and your code is good and other developers can reproduce the issue, then it's a bug.  Otherwise, your code needs some work.  I'm not a PHP guy, but your code looks fine.

Comment: I was just getting set to do that after a couple of days and found that the messages had come through perhaps after a delay of some hours or more. I wonder if some delay is to be expected.

Comment: An hour delay is too much.  Should be a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test users can only send messages to other test users. If your other user is a real user, your own account for example, it will not send.
From Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

> Limitations
>
> We ensure that test users are exempt from Facebook spam or fake
>   account detection systems to ensure that you can test your app without
>   worrying about getting disabled.
>
> Also, to ensure that using test user accounts to test various
>   scenarios doesn't end up unintentionally creating spam, we enforce
>   certain limitations on what test users can do.
>
> Test users can interact with other test users only and not with real
>   users on site. Test users cannot fan a public Page or create public
>   content on them like writing on a Page's wall. A Test user can however
>   view and interact with the app tab on the Page if they are associated
>   with that app. They can be accessed and used by any developer of the
>   associated app. They only have test privileges on the associated app.
>   This implies that they can use the app in live mode or sandbox mode
>   but cannot edit any technical settings or access insights for that
>   app. A test user is always a test user and cannot be converted to a
>   normal user account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually am sending between test users.